# Laravel 10 - Breeze, React, Inertia - 419 error on initial install

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

Really not sure what to do here, I have set up a fresh `Laravel 10.0.3` application, installed `Laravel Breeze` and selected React and no to SSR.

I have migrated my DB and setup my .env, basically if I use `php artisan serve` the Inertia response works and does not error with a `419` however if I change the `APP_URL` in the env to a different domain other than `localhost`, the request does not work and returns the `419`.

How can I change the URL in my `.env` file and maintain the correct intertia response? Do I have to vendor publish some settings, or add my custom domain to a session config or any other config for that matter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, I had changed my `APP_URL` after I had loaded the page so the session cookie was old, after deleting my cookies it worked as expected.